# import "runtime/debug" performance penalty

Tags: go

Will this import statement:

> import "runtime/debug"

have any performance penalty on my application? does it somehow impact the runtime?
I'm using the 'debug' package to print stack trace in just case of unexpected panic.

Comment: The only impact importing an extra package can possibly have, is in compiled output size, and memory usage.

Comment: How about an imported package 'init' code.
Can't it potentially have code inside there, that will impact the execution of other code?
for example, profiling information?